# How to Reload Content of Panel bar item each time panelbar item is expanded?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

i am using a kendo Panel bar.
i am loading the dynemic Content for each item in panel bar from partial view.

What is need is i need to reload content of panel bar item each time item is selected.

when i first time select the item in panel bar it makes ajax request to server and fills the content in item. but when i select it second time it does not make request to server. it displays the old data which id fetched from server when i click first time on item.

is there any way i can reload content of item of panel bar each time item is expanded? How can i do this?

```
@(Html.Kendo().PanelBar()
.Name("QuickViewP")
.ExpandMode(PanelBarExpandMode.Single)
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
.Items(panelbar =>
{

    panelbar.Add()
            .Text("Account Summary")
            .Expanded(true)
            .ImageUrl(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/account-summary.png"))
            .LoadContentFrom("AccountSummary", "QuickView");

    panelbar.Add()
            .Text("Messages & Notifications")
            .ImageUrl(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/messages.png"))
            .LoadContentFrom("MessagesNotifications", "QuickView");

     panelbar.Add().Text("Investment Elections")
            .ImageUrl(Url.Content("~/Content/Images/investment.png"))
            .LoadContentFrom("InvestmentElections", "QuickView");

}).Events(events => events.Expand("QuickViewPExpand"))
```

i have Added event like this.
i m able to get new content every time panel item is expanded 
but i have one problem . when i click the panel item first time it sends 2 Get ajax request
to the server. after that whenever i click panel item it works properly. it send ajax request and fill the new content.

What should i do to send only one requst when the panel item is clicked first time ?

This is the script i m using .

```
<script>
    function QuickViewPExpand(e) {
        debugger;
        var panelBar = $("#QuickViewP").data("kendoPanelBar");


        var item = panelBar.select();

        //if (item.hasClass("k-state-active")) {
        //    panelBar.collapse(item);
        //} else {
        //    panelBar.expand(item);
        //}

        // reload the panel bar
        // This reloads all items in panel bar i just need to only reload the panelItem
        // which is clicked 
        //panelBar.reload("> .k-item");

        // I am uisng this to reload item which is clicked 
        panelBar.reload(item[0]);

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably do something like this:

```
var panelBar = $("#QuickViewP").kendoPanelBar({
    expand: refreshContent()
});

var refreshContent = function(){
    var panelBar = $("#QuickViewP").data("kendoPanelBar");
    // reload the panel bar
    panelBar.reload("> .k-item");
}
```

The syntax may not be exact, but should get you close.

Comment: thanks man. i got some result from this script. but i have one problem can you please saw the post i have edited the content and added the script i m using .can you plz tell me what should i do?